# Large HTML file size in Angular 17 prerender or SSR

Tags: angular, angular-ssr

I'm excited about the SSR and SSG capability in Angular. However, I have a problem:

I configure the cache using withHttpTransferCacheOptions. if I have a lot of text content on a page, the size of the HTML files becomes large because the JSON file of the content is placed below the HTML for caching. For example, if we want to put a long article on a web page, everything is duplicated and the size of the HTML file becomes large.

Is there a way to include the content only once in the HTML file.